# Is it possible to cancel a silent install on Windows

Tags: windows, installation

We have an installer wizard (written in .NET) which configures and kicks off a series of standard Windows installers.  The installers are run silently.  Right now, clicking "Cancel" on the wizard's dialog stops further installers from running, but does not stop whatever installer is running silently in the background.

Is there a way to send a installer running silently the equivalent of pressing the Cancel button on a non-silent install?  (I could kill the installer process, but I expect that that will leave a half-installed (and probably non-uninstallable) mess behind.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're creating new instances of these installers within your own installation wizard so I don't know how applicable this solution is going to be, but if you do have access to the actual (derived) System.Installer objects that correspond to the installers, calling the overridden System.Installer.Rollback() method of those objects should achieve the desired result. Let me know if this doesn't work and I can try helping you further.

Comment: The request from product marketing is to improve the responsiveness of the installers.  Right now, pressing cancel on the wizard stops things after the current silent installer has finished running, which can be minutes later.  We post a message explaining what is happening, but people don't like it.  This would make the delay longer, though it would improve the result.
I'm guessing it would not be acceptable.

PS: I am creating new instances.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm afraid I don't know of any way to instantly stop the installation process without straight up killing it. It seems like you would need to rollback at some point to remove what's already been installed.

Comment: When you cancel a Windows Installer installation (by pressing the Cancel button on a non-silent install) it rolls back what it has done.  This is usually much faster than letting it complete and then running an uninstall.